# Inconsistent Android ICS keyboard behavior with <input type="number"> in PhoneGap app

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am seeing inconsistent keyboard behavior when using `<input type="number">` inside my Phonegap jQuery Mobile app.  On Android 4.0.3, a simple page that includes `<input type="number">` properly displays the Android numeric keyboard when the input element gets the focus.  On more complicated pages, `<input type="number">` displays the default Android keyboard and not the numeric keyboard.

This only occurs when I run my app as a native app packaged via Phonegap on my Acer Iconia A200 tablet which is running Android 4.0.3.  If I run this same app on my iPad2 using iOS 5.1.1, all `<input type="number">` elements properly display the numeric keyboard.  If I run this app under Google Chrome on the Acer tablet, the proper keyboard is displayed for all `<input type="number">` elements.

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.1 and Phonegap 1.8.1.

Is there something under jQuery Mobile that would cause `type="number"` to be ignored?  And is there some way via HTML / JavaScript to force the numeric keyboard to display when an  element gets the focus?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing this line from your CSS. This line was to avoid flickering on android phones, but it's not required now.

```
.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important;    
}
```

I tried resolving issues on Nexus, but trying to resolve one generates other issues. Transition performance can be poor on upgraded devices

Reference: [Jquery Mobile Supported Platforms](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/about/platforms.html)

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap, ICS (Android 4.0.3/4.0.4), and JQuery Mobile(JQM) do not play nice together at all!

I'm having keyboard issues, page (ajax) transitions issues, jquery validation issues - All of this has led me to the frustrating conclusion that ICS and JQM are not compatible!

The most frustrating part about it is that *sometimes* the pages do work, and other times they don't - totally inconsistent behavior! Grrrr!

JQTouch also does not play nice with ICS/Phonegap... although appears to work slightly bettter than JQM.

As far as i can tell, you have to implement a pure HTML/CSS/JS webpage if your using ICS/Phonegap.

All my testing was done via USB debugging on a 10.1 Samsung Galaxy Tab II on Eclipse.